# Getting the time complexity of below recursive implementation

Tags: algorithm, tree, complexity-theory

```
/* Function to get diameter of a binary tree */
int diameter(struct node * tree)
{
   /* base case where tree is empty */
    if (tree == 0)
     return 0;

  /* get the height of left and right sub-trees */
  int lheight = height(tree->left);
  int rheight = height(tree->right);

  /* get the diameter of left and right sub-trees */
  int ldiameter = diameter(tree->left);
  int rdiameter = diameter(tree->right);


  return max(lheight + rheight + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter));
}


int height(struct node* node)
{
   /* base case tree is empty */
   if(node == NULL)
       return 0;

   /* If tree is not empty then height = 1 + max of left
      height and right heights */   
    return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
}
```

How the time complexity of finding diameter of tree with this implementation is O(n^2) where n is the number of nodes in the tree ??

Comment: Just a thought. Cant we memoize the height, should we calculate every time?

Comment: I know this implementation is not optimal , I know another O(n) time algorithm , but I need to understand how the time complexity of this implementation is o(n^2) ?

Comment: O(N)? Which is that? I know one algorithm which is to do DFS from the root and find the farthest node (FN1). Then do DFS to find the farthest node from FN1 which will give the diameter.

Comment: The above implementation can be optimized to O(n) by calculating the height in the same recursion rather than calling a height() separately.

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n^2) because height calculation is also recursive. 
You can write a recurrence relation and solve it.

Else by [Master's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

You can see that f(n) is linear and hence c = 1 
So the complexity is log a to b when a is 4 (recursion used 4 times) and b is 2 (on half of the tree)

Answer (score 0):

Let `D()` denote the `diameter()` and `H()` denote the `height()`. For convenience let us assume the Binary Tree is `Complete Binary Tree` so that the left sub tree and the right sub tree has equal number of elements. Let us also assume that there are `N` elements in the Binary Tree. Now the time complexity of diameter function can be represented using the following recurrence relation.

```
D(N) = 2D(N/2) + 2H(N/2) + c1  ----- 1
```

Because of the following recursive calls in the `diameter()`,

```
  int lheight = height(tree->left);
  int rheight = height(tree->right);

  int ldiameter = diameter(tree->left);
  int rdiameter = diameter(tree->right);
```

Now let us analyze the `height()`,

The recurrence relation denoting the time complexity of `height()` is,

```
H(N) = 2H(N/2) + c2  ------ 2
```

Because of the following recursive calls in the `height()`,

```
return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
```

Now `H(N) = O(N logN)` by applying Master Theorem on 2.

Substitute this in 1, We get,

```
D(N) = 2D(N/2) + c3 N logN + c1   ------ 3
```

Solve **3** using Master Theorem, We get `D(N) = O(N logN)`.

So the complexity of the recursive function `diameter()` is `O(N logN)`